# C# using LoadFile or ReadallLines on RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a problem on a few systems that when we are trying to load the RichTextBox the program becomes unresponsive, we cannot do anything and will have to kill it via Taskmanager.
its working on most systems but a few systems located in a different country there seems to be problem.

we have tried something as simple as :

```
private void testing4()
{
    richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"C:\testing.logs", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
}
```

If we decide to use a normal TextBox it appears to be working using .net 4.5, but it still becomes unresponsive. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions when you try to load the text file? Maybe there is a permission problem that causes your website to be unresponsive

Comment: File sharing issue?  File in use somewhere else, I mean?

Comment: we are sure its not in use somewhere else, we are validated that, as we thought that to be the issue as well.
but its only used by the program, and only locally on the PC

Comment: RichTextBox can be slow converting UTF8 text if its outside the ASCII range. Perhaps that's the issue? (There's an old thread about it [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/259f8f60-34ec-401b-bdd1-2a5168f232f6/setting-richtextbox-characterset-to-utf8-to-improve-text-loadingrendering-speed?forum=winforms))

Comment: How big is this log file?  It can go catatonic for quite a while, thrashing the paging file badly when the file contains many megabytes worth of text.  Use Task Manager to diagnose, add the "PF delta" column.

Comment: We have tried with both a small file 5Kb with only 100 lines of text
and we have a 10 MB file (which will be the normal size) but same issue

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(@"C:\testing.logs"))
{
  richTextBox1.AppendText(line+Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using framework 4.5, you can do it async, as in MSDN example:

```
public async void ReadFile()
{
    string filePath = @"C:\testing.logs";

    if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("file not found: " + filePath);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            string text = await ReadTextAsync(filePath);
            richTextBox1.AppendText(text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private async Task<string> ReadTextAsync(string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read,
        bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
        int numRead;
        while ((numRead = await sourceStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer, 0, numRead);
            sb.Append(text);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Source: [Using Async for File Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx)